# Bluemix Secure Gateway JDBC connection to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ssl, ibm-cloud, gateway, secure-gateway

I managed to create a connection from my sample Java application running on Bluemix and a MySQL database running on my local machine using Secure Gateway service and Docker. No security.

Now I am trying to find out how should TLS be configured. Should I establish the TLS connection in my Java code and make the corresponding configuration in MySQL? I thought this would be a configuration between Secure Gateway and Docker. If this is the case, how should I configure the communication between them? And, what is the token required for?

Is there a tutorial on how to implement this communication in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

TLS can be configured between your java app and the Secure Gateway Cloud host and port and between the Docker client and your MySQL database. These are done separately.

Docs for these two configurations:

Application side TLS: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/sg_023.html#sg_007

Client side TLS:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/sg_023.html#sg_011

The traffic through the tunnel between the docker client and the secure gateway server is always encrypted, there are no options around this.

For security reasons, it is best to use TLS on the application side. This would require your Java app to connect with the Secure Gateway cloud host:port using TLS. I don't have a tutorial for this in Java.

The security token is used for both the REST API and starting the docker client if the Enforce Security Token option has been checked when creating the gateway.